# Fluid Menu ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

We are developing a website with a drop down menu. The problem is the menu needs to be dynamic since the Parent and Child will be place under a single menu. This means that a single menu may contain multiple parents with multiple children. These parents/children are coming from a database.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/h9o.png/

When hover the set of parent menu and children will be shown

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/fiz5.png/

The number of rows depends on the number of Parent and Children, The children will always under the parents, Children will not be broken into two different column. Which means the rows and columns are created dynamically based on the data that coming from the database. Any idea how to make this?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: I have done same for one of my websites, give me a second, i will post answer

Comment: we have tried using tables (with one column), our algorithm is we have created 3 tables, we check the number of parents/childrens, divide the number of columns, base on our specs, say we have 20 parents/child, the number of rows per table(column) will be 10, we keep on adding the parent and child, if the number of rows reaches 10 but there are still some child the row will expand to hold the children of the parent before moving to the next table(column)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of menu solutions on the net.

I've used JQuery UI menu http://jqueryui.com/menu/ .

Just output your menu items as `<li>`'s and run the Jquery UI function `.menu();` as they do in the example in the link page. The items in the menu can either be links to other pages or postbacks to the same page. If you postback you could in the item assign some value to a hidden field that you check in the code behind.

Comment: i have tried jquery but it doesnt support multic column that contain mulitple parent with multiple child menus

Comment: Ok, I missed the second picture. I googled and found this word press plugin: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/demo-wordpress-jquery-vertical-mega-menu-plugin.html# that seems promising. Never used it though. Perhaps it is possible to use with asp.net also?

Comment: Already seen that website, Already tried it, it only displays static links, and not dynamic that are coming from the database.

Comment: Well the menu is just &;lt;li&gt;s that are styled as a menu. You can write codebehind code to output any `<li&>`s you like and put any `<a href = ...>` into them you like. So you could do the dynamic part your self...